# Not partial specialisation but still incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following program:

```
template <class T>
class A {
    void f();
};

template <class T>
class B { };

template <class T>
void A<B<T> >::f() {

}
```

I get the error:

```
invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A<B<T> >’
```

Does this count as partial specialisation? I always thought partial specialisation was specialising only a struct subset of template parameters.

Is there any work around ao I can accomplish specialising a template with a templated type?

Comment: A non-partial specialisation is not a template. So if your thing has template parameters, it cannot be a full specialisation. And since it is some kind of specialisation, it's got to be a partial one.

Comment: the number of duplicates on this topic is overwhelming. instead of trying to partially specialize a member function just let the overload resolution [do the job](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86eaaae17992e574)

Comment: You can't get a definition for A<int>::f out of that template, so I'd call it partial.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to partially specialize only one member function, you must specialize whole class

```
template <class T>
class A {
    void f();
};

template <class T>
class B { };

template <class T>
class A<B<T> >{
    void f() { /* put here what you need in this special case */}; 
};
```